# The name 'cat' does not exist in current context

Tags: c#, object

I'm getting an error for the 'cat' object I'm creating. It says it doesn't exist in the current context even though I just created it. I don't even know where exactly the main method is to add this so I'm just putting it in the partial class part. I'm sure that's not right but reading my book is not helpful, it just says to put it but not exactly where inside Visual Basic. I'm used to Java, where you can just create a main class in notepad but there isn't one in VB. The code I'm asking about is in bold, not actually part of the Pet class.

I haven't tried much, considering they are in the same method. it should recognize it but it isn't. every answer I see on here/Google the person wasn't creating the object properly. To me, it looks exactly as it should be:

```
Pet cat = new Pet("10", "Fido", "Cat");
```

Here's a part of the class:

```
namespace PetClassesandObjects
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
        Pet cat = new Pet("10", "Fido", "Cat");
        cat.GetName();
```

I will be using the object to call the methods in the Pet class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code is at the class level, but it needs to be inside a method.

At the class level you are defining what the object *is*, but in the methods you define what it *does*.  The logical operations it performs, etc.  Simply put your code inside a method:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    public void DoSomething()
    {
        Pet cat = new Pet("10", "Fido", "Cat");
        cat.GetName();
    }
}
```

As for what `GetName()` itself is expected to do or what output you expect to see or when you would call the `DoSomething()` method, that's all up to you.  But the operation itself would be within a method.

You *can* at least define the variable at the class level if you still want to, if that object defines what your form *is*:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    Pet cat = new Pet("10", "Fido", "Cat");

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    public void DoSomething()
    {
        cat.GetName();
    }
}
```

(Side note: Name your methods something better than "Do Something".  This was just a contrived example to illustrate the point.  Good names for variables/methods/classes/etc. are important and will help you understand your own code.)

Answer (score 1):

So continuing with what David commented on, you could just add a Button to your form and Double Click it to create the stub handler.  From there you could display the return value in a Label, for instance:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    Pet cat = new Pet("10", "Fido", "Cat");

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        label1.Text = cat.GetName();
    }

}
```

Comment: thank you! I put my cat.GetName() inside a button click event and it worked. it's just asking me for parameters now :'( but i can figure that one out on my own

Comment: You have to pass parameters to `GetName()`, if I understand correctly.